# AngularDart Template Error: Attribute [...] is not allowed here

Tags: templates, dart, angular-dart

I'm upgrading my version 1 AngularDart to version 4. I'm getting an error from my IDE on the template:

```
template: '<span class="cite-text" [citable]="citableForCitation()">{{citationText}}</span>',
```

error:

```
Attribute [citable] in not allowed here
```

I see a very similar format in the darlang hero app (4.0):

```
template: '''
  <h1>Tour of Heroes</h1>
  <hero-app-main [hero]="hero"></hero-app-main>''',
```

In my code, I'm referring to a method where the tutorial looks to be referring to a variable. So, I have to change the format in the template or change something in the method. Any idea which?

This is an example of the use of the template:

```
<citation bentry=1>[Lin92]</citation>
```

This is the complete program:

```
library citation_component;

import 'dart:html';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart';

import 'package:citable/citable/citable.dart' show CitableModel;

@Component(
    selector: 'citation',
    template: '<span class="cite-text" [citable]="citableForCitation()">{{citationText}}</span>',
    styleUrls: const ['citation.css'],
    directives: const [formDirectives])

class CitationComponent
{
  @Input() int bentry;
  //@NgAttr('bentry')
  //int bentry;

  // Set up the decorator
  static final citable = new Expando<CitableModel>();

  final Element element;
  String citationText;

  CitationComponent(this.element)
  {
    citationText = element.innerHtml;
  }

  CitableModel citableForCitation()
  {
    if (citable[this] == null)
    {
      citable[this] = new CitableModel(bentry);
    }
    return citable[this];
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `[citable]`? That's for a property.

Comment: It's very similar to a tool tip

Comment: There is no `@Input() SomeType citable;` in your component. Why do you think `[citable]="citableForCitation()"` should work?

Comment: The old code works fine with the older version of AngularDart. The only change I made was to add @Input in place of the commented out code below it. The code is a reworked version of an AngularDart tutorial, which I can't find anymore. [citable]="citableForCitation()" doesn't work. I'm asking what the replacement is.

Comment: [attr.citable]="citableForCitation()"

Comment: @matanlurey, that has no effect